# In Windows, what is the meaning of a crash with exception code equal to STATUS_WAKE_SYSTEM_DEBUGGER 0x80000007?

Tags: windows, windbg

I have a crashdump created by DrWatson, the exception code is 0x80000007 STATUS_WAKE_SYSTEM_DEBUGGER and the message is "{Kernel Debugger Awakened} The system debugger was awakened by an interrupt." (from here: 2.3.1 NTSTATUS values http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588(v=prot.10).aspx )

I cannot find any documentation about it. What is its meaning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick trip to Google brought up [this forum post](http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.kernel/2007-04/msg00195.html).  Basically some DLL crashed inside DllMain and thus the loader lock was abandoned.  The injected thread that the debugger creates then gets stuck during its DllMain(THREAD_ATTACH) call.  After some time, the operating system uses a "wake debugger" approach and that is what the debugger ends up seeing instead of the original exception.  Sounds plausible.